# How to fetch all roles of systemuser?

Tags: dynamic, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to pull all roles assigned to a systemuser. I think I require to use associated entities but I am not sure how should I proceed with the approach.
Here is my code snippet:

```csharp
Uri organizationUri = new Uri(this.ConnectionString);
Uri homeRealmUri = null;
ClientCredentials credentials = new ClientCredentials();
credentials.UserName.UserName = ConfigUserName;
credentials.UserName.Password = ConfigPassword;

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy orgProxy = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.OrganizationServiceProxy(organizationUri, homeRealmUri, credentials, null);
IOrganizationService _service = (IOrganizationService)orgProxy;

Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity account = new Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity("systemuser");
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression
{
    EntityName = account.LogicalName,
    ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true)
};
DataCollection<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity> users = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;

// fetch assigned roles of users
```

Comment: Did the link from James help? If so, accept his reply as an answer. If not, let us know and someone will post a shorter version of the source code for you. I know the examples may feel a bit overwhelming sometimes. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my implementation to pull all roles of specific user

```csharp
QueryExpression query = new QueryExpression();
query.EntityName = "role";
query.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);

LinkEntity role = new LinkEntity();
role.LinkFromEntityName = "role";
role.LinkFromAttributeName = "roleid";
role.LinkToEntityName = "systemuserroles";
role.LinkToAttributeName = "roleid";

LinkEntity userRoles = new LinkEntity();
userRoles.LinkFromEntityName = "systemuserroles";
userRoles.LinkFromAttributeName = "systemuserid";
userRoles.LinkToEntityName = "systemuser";
userRoles.LinkToAttributeName = "systemuserid";

ConditionExpression conditionExpression = new ConditionExpression();
conditionExpression.AttributeName = "systemuserid";
conditionExpression.Operator = ConditionOperator.Equal;
conditionExpression.Values.Add(userId);

userRoles.LinkCriteria = new FilterExpression();
userRoles.LinkCriteria.Conditions.Add(conditionExpression);

role.LinkEntities.Add(userRoles);
query.LinkEntities.Add(role);

DataCollection<Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity> userRoles = _service.RetrieveMultiple(query).Entities;
return userRoles;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a sample on the MSDN for checking users security roles, should help you finish this off.

[Sample: Determine Whether a User has a Role](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj602961.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

The following Linq query using the generated early-bound CRM entities will do what you're after:

```
var query = from user in context.SystemUserSet
            join userRoles in context.SystemUserRolesSet on user.SystemUserId equals userRoles.SystemUserId
            join role in context.RoleSet on userRoles.RoleId equals role.RoleId
            where user.DomainName == '<username>'
            select role;
```

Information on generating early-bound entities can be found here: [CrmSvcUtil usage](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ff681561.aspx)